# Detect current browser for use with caniuse-api

Tags: reactjs, next.js, caniuse

How do I obtain the **current** browser to pass into `isSupported`? I.e.:

```
caniuse.isSupported('border-radius', <my **actual** browser here>);
```

Library: https://github.com/Nyalab/caniuse-api

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser)

Comment: There was [no response](https://github.com/Nyalab/caniuse-api/issues/50) 5 years ago, so don't hold your breath waiting for someone to implement this.

Comment: @FiodorovAndrei Thank you but no, that does not answer the question. It is allowed to use any browser they like, as long as they support some specific functionality from caniuse.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks, that's too bad. It would make the library more useful in a practical sense.